# How to do smart animations in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation, core-animation

Today I am using Security scanning app in xiaomi phone on that app while I clicking button it will open animation screen and scanning process. My question is how is that possible embed animation in activity. I have only little knowledge about animation in Android studio.
[image: this is image from that app]

If I want to do this in my app, How to do that ? .

I have little bit know that android studio animation  for moving, up to down animation but how is this possible.
Help me